# What data structure represents these images?

Tags: data-structures

1. Items below with the same number, are the same item
2. I do not think there can be a cycle.

edit:

Image is no longer needed, (see 1 & 2 above). It is not a graph because a graph requires a set of items and a set does not allow duplicate items. I've already worked through this issue but the visual is misleading.

Comment: What images are referred to in the question title?

Comment: @Michael, sorry, its due to some issues I'd rather not go into, but I will put it back up later today, no worries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, looks like a graph.  You might be able to make the distinction of an acyclic, directed graph since you're wanting to orient the structure a specific way.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph

Comment: Thanks, confirmation is appreciated. Marking as answer. I have an algorithms book I'm using as reference and I'll refer to the DAG there. Thanks!